# Passing multi-dimensional arrays into functions and editing values

Tags: c, arrays

I'm working on creating a simple wordsearch generator but having a problem passing a two dimensional array through a function and editing the value inside. I have declared my array in main as such:

```
char tableValues[xsize-1][ysize-1];
```

I'm filling each point in the array with a - in main, then passing it through to a function that fills the array with random letters and returns.

```
void fillTable(char *tableValues){
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < xsize ; i++ ){
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < ysize ; j++ ){
            if ( tableValues[i][j]=='-')
                tableValues[i][j] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[rand () % 26];
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that an error gets flagged at the "tableValues[i][j]" parts, I'm not sure how else I'd edit individual points in an array with pointers. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

I am calling my function as

```
fillTable((char *)tableValues);
```

Comment: How do you call your function?

Comment: Since you are getting an error, you should include it in your question.

Comment: fillTable((char *)tableValues); , I have a similar function that does work that prints the table out, I call it as "printTable((char *)tableValues);" so I assumed I could call it the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-2d-array-parameter-c/),

```
void fillTable(char *tableValues){
for ( int i = 0 ; i < xsize ; i++ ){
    for ( int j = 0 ; j < ysize ; j++ ){
        if ( *((tableValues +i*(xsize-1))+j)=='-')
            *((tableValues+i*(xsize-1))+j) = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[rand () % 26];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I do that in my other function, printTable. I've tried printing before and after the fillTable function, and my table with the "-"s prints fine, but gets stuck during the function fillTable

Comment: @Defa1t that is unecessarily complicated, write code that looks natural when you read it, not just code that works. And parametrize as much as you can, that way your code is much more extensible and scalable.

Comment: That is not correct. The array size is `xsize-1` x `ysize-1`.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an 2d array and the function expects a pointer to `char` which is not compatible, specially accessing it with two subscript operators is wrong, you will need to change your function signature to something like

```
char (int xsize, int ysize, char array[xsize][ysize])
 { 
 }
```

don't declare `xsize` and `ysize` as globals, just pass them to the functions so that way the functions are really reusable, otherwise there is very little to gain in wrinting functions.

Answer (score 0):

The function should be defined like

```
void fillTable( char ( *tableValues )[ysize-1], int rows )
{
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < ysize - 1 ; j++ )
        {
            if ( tableValues[i][j] == '-' )
                tableValues[i][j] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[rand () % 26];
        }
    }
}
```

provided that `ysize` is some defined constant.

Otherwise if your compiler supports Variable Length Arrays then it can be defined like

```
void fillTable( int rows, int cols, char tableValues[rows][cols] )
{
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < cols ; j++ )
        {
            if ( tableValues[i][j] == '-' )
                tableValues[i][j] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[rand () % 26];
        }
    }
}
```